# Rotate AVAssetWriter's output 180 deg about the x-axis

Tags: ios, video, quicktime, cgaffinetransform, avassetwriter

I'm creating a Quicktime movie file using `AVAssetWriter`. Currently the output video is "upside down". In theory I can correct this by rotating the video 180 degrees about the horizontal axis (essentially "flipping" the video). **What's the best way to do this?**

Currently I'm trying to assign a `CGAffineTransform` to `myAVAssetWriterInput.transform`. Perhaps `CGAffineTransformMake(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)` will allow me to specify the correct affine transformation matrix?

Neither the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) nor [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) gives a clear explanation on how an affine transformation matrix works. And there might be a better way all together.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
myAVAssetWriterInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

if you want to rotate the video 180 degrees around z-axis, or

```
myAVAssetWriterInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

if you want to reflect in x-axis

Answer (score 0):

`[AVAssetTrack preferredTransform]` will return the right CGAffineTransform.

You can assign this CGAffineTransform to `writeInput`.